# Lync2013 on VS 2013 LyncClient.GetClient() throw TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, lync-2013

I am a newbie in Lync. I had developed the first application by C# on VS 2013 and VS 2012 with Lync SDK 2013. I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/08/microsoft-lync-desktop-development-how-to-get-started/) for my winform application as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model;

namespace LyncStart
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();

            MessageBox.Show(lyncClient.State + "");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run application, an error occur:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in LyncStart.exe
Additional information: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient' threw an exception.*

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you do not have the Lync Client running, checkout step 0 in the mentioned article for more details.

Comment: I had already run and signed in Lync Client before running application. I had checked on VS 2012, but still got this error :(. Target framework is .Net Framework 4 like the guide on [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj933215.aspx)

Comment: Which versions of the Lync client and the Lync SDK are you using?

Comment: I used Lync Client 2013 and Lync SDK 2013 ^^. I had found my problem and fix it. My problem is imported **Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll**. I removed this reference and it worked.